# ASP.NET how to display data without GridView

Tags: asp.net

I am newbie in ASP.NET.
I have prepared an arraylist of Product and want to display in the page.
Easiest way is binding the arraylist to GridView.

But I don't have flexibility there, since it will automatically generate a TABLE behind the scene.
Is there any other way to give us flexibility to really control the HTML output, for e.g i want to display using UL tag instead of TABLE tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var products = new ArrayList();
products.Add("product1");
products.Add("product2");
products.Add("product3");

var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var product in products)
{
    builder.Append("<li>" + product + "</li>");
}

Response.Write("<ul>" + builder.ToString() + "</ul>");
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But could you explain me more what shall I do in aspx and aspx.cs files? Your comment make sense for me only at ASP (not ASP.NET??)

Comment: @iwan- the code above can be added in the `Page_Load` method or some event handler like for a button in the code behind `*.aspx.cs` file of the `*.aspx` page file.  

The `Response.Write` will return the raw HTML `<ul><li>product1</li><li>product2</li><li>product3</li></ul>` created by the stringbuilder to the clientside browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can prefer using `Repeater Control` instead. With Repeater's templates, you can easily inject your html output to your output.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) there's an exapmle of using Repeater. Actually example also try to add a table but, the topic is to show you how to use templates.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer. it seems the right answer the only thing from what I saw the repeater needs DataSourceID -- meanwhile I have an ArrayList. Any clue?

Comment: No you can set your ArrayList to Repeater's DataSource property and call DataBind Method.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Response.Write("<ul><li>item1</li><li>item1</li><li>item1</li><li>item1</li></ul>")
```

You get all the control u need with that

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But could you explain me more what shall I do in aspx and aspx.cs files? Your comment make sense for me only at ASP (not ASP.NET??)

Comment: Oh ok.. now i understand that we could write Response.Write inside aspx.cs -- but then it kinds of breaking master page. So i add label and populate the label with the right UL/LI tags. Thanks!!!!